# Swagger request after going through Google OAuth flow

Tags: express, swagger, passport.js, google-oauth, swagger-ui

Is there any way to authenticate swagger via Google OAuth so every request has the user property on the request (req.user)?

If I navigate to `localhost:5000/api/current_user` after going through google auth flow, I get a user object back.

```
app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
```

But if I use swagger and hit that same endpoint, req.user is null.

After going through the Google OAuth flow using the passport library, a cookie gets added to every request after with the user (or any other property you want i.e. userId). For example, on every request, the user will be added via the req.user property which is great. I am trying to setup Swagger which doesnt have the user on the request (req.user) because it hasn't gone through the Google OAuth Flow. In practice, I've seen people get a bearer token from their application first(not using google OAuth but username and password auth) then copying that over to swagger's bearer token input to authenticate.